# Find the min/max element of an Array containing strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I obtain the max number of a JavaScript Array containing strings?

```
const array = ['a', 3, 4, 2] // should return 4
```

Here's my answer but I got NaN

```
function maxNum(arr) {
 for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  return Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
 }
}
maxNum(array) //NaN
```

Comment: what do you mean by the max in an array of strings? Or should it ignore when it is not a number and only get the max number?

Comment: `const maxNum = arr => Math.max(...arr.filter(e => typeof e === 'number'));`

Comment: @Dalorzo max number* sorry. I'm trying to find the max number in the array and I don't know how when there's a string in it

Comment: So if you did a search on how to filter only numbers in array you would find numerous results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to check for number only.

```js
const array = ['a', 3, 4, 2] // should return 4

function myArrayMax(x) {
  return Math.max(...x.filter(x => typeof x === 'number')); //result is 4
}
console.log(myArrayMax(array)) //4
```

Using [Math.max.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method

```js
const array = ['a', 3, 4, 2] // should return 4

function myArrayMax(x) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, x.filter(x => typeof x === 'number')); //result is 4
}
console.log(myArrayMax(array)) //4
```

Comment: What is `this`?

Comment: @charlietfl you can use `this` or `null` - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: My point is `this` is window if run in client side global space so really makes no sense to use it here

Comment: @charlietfl changed to it `null` if that makes more sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna ignore strings and only take max from numbers. [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) accepts numbers, not an array.

```js
let array = ['a', 3, 4, 2] // should return 4
array = array.filter(a => !isNaN(Number(a)));
let max = Math.max(...array);
console.log(max);
```

Comment: `Number(a)` is not a good idea, not even like this. Take an input of `[-1, 0]`.

Comment: My interpretation of the question was to ignore strings, which this doesn't, if the string can be converted to number. However, that's not completely clear from the question, so i guess it's up to OP to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
//as a note: `isNaN` have weird behaviour ..
```

MDN ref: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

```js
const array = ['a', 3, 4, 2] 

let result = Math.max(...(array.filter(el=>!isNaN(el))))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think more efficient could be using **`array.prototype.reduce`**:

```js
var result = ['a', 3, 4, 2].reduce( 
      (a,b) => isNaN(a) ? b : (a>=b) ? a : b , 0) ;
console.log(result);
```

Because it only loops one time the array to get the highest number. The option of filtering and then `Math.max` will require 2 loops.